# Using Ext.js hotkeys to call existing function

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, hotkeys

I am trying to set up hotkeys in an Ext.js project. My code is below.

```
_setHotKeys: function(values, button){
    var hotKeyMap = {
            target: document, 
            binding:[]
        }; 

        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            if(values[i].hotkey){
                hotKeyMap.binding.push({
                    key: values[i].hotkey, 
                    fn: this._handleFillInValueButtonToggle(button, true)
                }); 
            }   
        }
        console.log(hotKeyMap); 
        var keyMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(hotKeyMap); 
},
```

I have another function, `_handleFillInValueButtonToggle` that I would like to be called when a hot key is pressed.  The result of `console.log(hotKeyMap)` shows that the `fn` is never being set to this function, but instead to undefined:

```
{
    target: document, 
    binding: [
        { fn: undefined, key: "e"}, 
        { fn: undefined, key: "c"}, 
        { fn: undefined, key: "n"}, 
        { fn: undefined, key: "d"}, 
    ]
}
```

How can I successfully call this function when the hotkey is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the function directly, call a function that calls the function you want, while passing in scope.

```
hotKeyMap.binding.push({
    key: values[i].hotkey, 
    fn: function(){
        this._handleFillInValueButtonToggle(button, true);
    }, 
    scope: this
});
```